# meta-analysis with metacont with limited inputs

Tags: r

I am learning to conduct a meta-analysis with R's package `meta`.

I have a dataset containing each study's mean difference and its lower/upper bound.

However, function `metacont` requires me to input the number of participants, mean, and standard deviation of the experimental and control group (i.e. Ne, Me, Se, Nc, Mc, Sc).

What can I do if I still want to conduct the meta-analysis?

Answer (score 0):

You can conduct a meta-analysis from a mean difference and its standard error using the generic metagen function. If the lower and upper bound for each study is a 95% confidence interval, then you can get the standard error for each study by subtracting its lower bound from its upper bound and dividing by approximately 3.92 (`qnorm(0.975) * 2` to be exact).

https://handbook-5-1.cochrane.org/chapter_7/7_7_7_2_obtaining_standard_errors_from_confidence_intervals_and.htm

```
library(meta)

# Define xample data
df <- structure(list(md = c(1.09, 0.43, 1.53, -0.02, -0.86),
                     ll = c(0.05, 0.28, 0.06, -6.49, -1.5),
                     ul = c(2.12, 0.58, 3, 6.44, -0.22)),
                row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

# Calculate the standard error for each study
z <- qnorm(0.975) * 2
df$se <- (df$ul - df$ll) / z

# Conduct the meta-analysis
metagen(md, se, data=df)
```

Comment: But I'm wondering how this package can complete meta-analysis without knowing how many people are included in each study (i.e. the no. of each study).

Comment: A meta-analysis is basically an inverse variance (i.e., squared standard error) weighted mean of the effect estimates, so you don't need the sample size except insofar as it's necessary to calculate the variance. The metacont function conveniently calculates the variances for you from the standard deviation and sample size of each study, but even without that information you can conduct a meta-analysis as long as you are able to calculate the standard error or variance yourself